# Linked List pointer error makes no sense

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have created a `ListNode` class:

```
ListNode::ListNode()
{
  value = 0;
  next = NULL;
  previous = NULL:
}
```

So I have this function that is supposed to return the node that is right after the head:

```
ListItr List::first()
{
  ListItr* first = new ListItr(head->next);
  return first;
}
```

I am passing the argument `head->next` to this function:

```
ListItr::ListItr(ListNode* theNode)
{
  current = theNode;
}
```

When I try to compile my code I get an error that says `no viable conversion from 'ListItr *' to 'ListItr'`

The note under the error says:

```
`candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no know conversion from 'ListItr *' to 'const ListItr &' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my code sense the function expects a point to be passed and that's what I am passing.

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428930/no-viable-conversion-from-class-to-class/32429505

Comment: The error you say you get is slightly different to the note underneath. One is saying it can't convert from `ListItr*` to `ListItr`, but the other says can't convert from `ListItr*` to `ListNode*`. Your `ListItr` constructor takes a `ListNode*`; however, if you try and pass a `ListItr*` it will assume you are trying to implicitly copy-construct. If you are getting confused with types, it might help to rename them into completely different words.

Comment: I know that's why I'm confused! I don't really understand the error message and I can't see the problem in the code.

Comment: Please add the declaration of `head` (and the declaration of whatever class it is) into your question for more clarification.

Comment: It's at the very top of the post.

Comment: That's the _constructor_ for `ListNode`, but it would be far more useful to have the **declaration** of `ListNode`: that is, the part the has `class ListNode` etc. Ultimately we'd need to be able to see what **type** `next` is.

Comment: Well you declared `List::first` to return an object, but then you're trying to return a pointer...

Comment: Did you create another account to ask about the same bad code? [This is you, right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428930/no-viable-conversion-from-class-to-class) [And is this another separate account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425692/building-a-double-linked-list-in-c)

Comment: @Blastfurnace Aww, I missed that actually. We should have closed as a duplicate. But we'll, that question is doomed either.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call `new` to create **everything**, this isn't Java. Only use new when you want to create a pointer to a dynamically allocated object. Here you are just trying to create and return a normal object, not a dynamically created object.

```
ListItr List::first()
{
  ListItr* first = new ListItr(head->next);
  return first;
}
```

should be

```
ListItr List::first()
{
  return ListItr(head->next);
}
```